# Populate HTML form with data saved on Local Storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, local-storage

My application saves the filled form data (input fields with their ID's and values) to Local Storage and even loads them back successfully, separating the parsed ID's and values back up again.

The problem is that I can't manage to pre-fill the form back up from the data that has been saved to Local Storage once the page reloads. Saved data remains in browser's resources, and console logs the correct values for each input field. However, nothing shows up on the page itself.

Here is an example of my HTML structure:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post">
   <input type="submit" onclick="dataSave();" value="Save">
   <input class="formField" type="checkbox">Task done!
   <input class="formField" type="text">How it went?
</form>
```

And here is the current JavaScript that does the saving and loading to Local Storage:

```js
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined"){
    
    // Loading data
    function dataLoad(){
        var inputParse = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('fieldString'));
        var inputId;
        var inputValue;
        var inputType;

        $.each(inputParse, function(key, value){
            inputId = key;
            inputValue = value;

            if (inputValue === "true" || inputValue === "false"){
                inputType = inputValue;
            }
        });

      
        $(".formField").each(function(){
            inputId = this.id;
            document.getElementById(inputId);
 
            if (inputType === "true"){
                $(inputId).attr("checked", "checked");
            } else {
                $(inputId).val(inputValue);
            }
        });
    }
    
    // Saving data
    function dataSave(){
        var mngrFields = {};
        
        $(".mngr-field").each(function(){
            if (this.type == "radio" || this.type == "checkbox"){
                mngrFields[this.id] = this.checked;
            } else {
                mngrFields[this.id] = this.value;
            }
        });
        localStorage.setItem('fieldString', JSON.stringify(mngrFields));
    }
```

And to run the `dataLoad()` after the page has loaded, I have a simple `dataLoad();` inside my `$(document).ready(function(){ });`.

**How can I get the form filled up with the saved data?** I have tried some `document.GetElementById` workarounds, but no luck.

Comment: Perhaps you should use `$('#'+inputId)` instead of `$(inputId)`, assuming you only save id's without the preceding `#`.

Comment: Thanks for noticing! Totally missed it. But still, it does not load up the data for the form. :(

Comment: Can you please show the output of `console.log(inputParse);`? It would be helpful to see how data is saved. Because populating fields should be straightforward enough if data is being inserted correctly to corresponding input types.

Comment: `inputParse` only returns `[object Object]` in return, is this because the content is saved to Local Storage? In Local Storage, the value of the `fieldString` key is following: `{"payment_type_mngr_1_01":false,"payment_type_mngr_1_02":"90%","payment_type_mngr_1_03":true,"payment_type_mngr_1_04":false,"payment_type_mngr_1_06":false,"payment_type_mngr_1_07":false,"payment_type_mngr_1_08":false,"payment_type_mngr_1_10":false,"payment_type_mngr_1_11":false,"payment_type_mngr_1_12":"0%"}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The task is simple:

- get localStorage content (but first check is it there);
- for each stored ID check the HTML type from the DOM (because you don't know it from current localStorage object);
- assign value or checked attribute (if is radio/checkbox) to it;

So here it is:

```
function dataLoad() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('fieldString') !== null) {
        var inputParse = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('fieldString'));
        $.each(inputParse, function (key, value) {
            var field = document.getElementById(key);
            if(field.type == 'radio' || field.type == 'checkbox'){
                field.checked = value;
            }else{
                field.value = value;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You can call the function automatically on document load or assign it to some button (like save action) - it's up to you.

Good luck!

Comment: Amazing! One issue though; I have jQueryUI sliders (that basically use the text-field to represent value) that will not load up to show their value. I can find the data stored in Local Storage, but it does not load. Tried to set a timeout to the `dataLoad();` but it only showed the text values without moving the sliders themselves. Any ideas on what could cause this / what could fix it?

Comment: Well, I need to see that code in order to answer how rest of the code shall iteract with that slider. i'm pretty sure it's matter of some additional function call or initializaton in order that slider to become active after data population, but cannot say nothing more without some lines of code.

Comment: But better close that topic (if your problem is resolved) and open new one.