# putting back values from local storage to html form

Tags: javascript, caching, local-storage

I am trying to cache my form data so that if user loses an internet connection and they comes back and recover the information through the local storage. I created a localstorage in which I am storing the entire form in JSON format.Upon refreshing the page, I want to show the data stored in local storage to automatically be filled in the fields.
I checked [Populate HTML form with data saved on Local Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38473924/populate-html-form-with-data-saved-on-local-storage) but its not working for me. The way I want it.My values are not getting loaded in the form that are in local storage.
How can I load the form with the values in local storage upon refreshing?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.onload = dataLoad();
});

function dataLoad() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('testObject') !== null) {
    var inputParse = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('testObject'));
    $.each(inputParse, function(key, value) {
      var field = document.querySelector("[name=" + key + "]");
      if (field.type == 'radio' || field.type == 'checkbox') {
        field.checked = field.value == value;
      } else {
        field.value = value;
      }
    });
  }
}

function CacheData() {
  var yourObject = $('#application-form').serializeObject();
  localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(yourObject));
}
jQuery.fn.serializeObject = function() {
  var formData = {};
  var formArray = this.serializeArray();
  for (var i = 0, n = formArray.length; i < n; ++i)
    formData[formArray[i].name] = formArray[i].value;
  return formData;
};
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="container body-content">
    <form id="application-form" action="/Application/Edit/2" method="post">
      <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" id="save-application" onclick="CacheData()" />
      <div class="form-horizontal" id="wrapper">
        <div class="form-group hidden">
          <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="ApplicationId">Application No.</label>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control" type="number" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Application No. field is required." id="ApplicationId" name="ApplicationId" value="2" />
            <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ApplicationId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="client" class="panel panel-default">
          <div id="client-collapse" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="ClientId">Client ID</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                  <input class="form-control input-right-align" readonly type="number" id="ClientId" name="ClientId" value="2" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Client_FirstName">First Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <input class="form-control" readonly type="text" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field First Name must be a string with a maximum length of 100." data-val-length-max="100" id="Client_FirstName" name="Client.FirstName" value="Test" />
                </div>
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Client_LastName">Last Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <input class="form-control" readonly type="text" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Last Name must be a string with a maximum length of 100." data-val-length-max="100" id="Client_LastName" name="Client.LastName" value="Tester" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       
        
        <div id="asa" class="panel panel-default">
          Alternate Signing Authority
          <div id="asa-collapse" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <table class="table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                      <input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Application ID field is required." id="AlternateSigningAuthorities_0__ApplicationId" name="AlternateSigningAuthorities[0].ApplicationId" value="2" />
                      <input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Created By must be a string with a maximum length of 255." data-val-length-max="255" id="AlternateSigningAuthorities_0__CreatedBy" name="AlternateSigningAuthorities[0].CreatedBy" value="PilotUser"
                      />
                      <input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Last Modified By must be a string with a maximum length of 255." data-val-length-max="255" id="AlternateSigningAuthorities_0__ModifiedBy" name="AlternateSigningAuthorities[0].ModifiedBy"
                        value="Unknown" />
                      <input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Client ID field is required." id="AlternateSigningAuthorities_0__ClientId" name="AlternateSigningAuthorities[0].ClientId" value="2" />
                      <input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field First Name must be a string with a maximum length of 100." data-val-length-max="100" id="AlternateSigningAuthorities_0__Client_FirstName" name="AlternateSigningAuthorities[0].Client.FirstName"
                        value="Test" />
                      <input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Last Name must be a string with a maximum length of 100." data-val-length-max="100" id="AlternateSigningAuthorities_0__Client_LastName" name="AlternateSigningAuthorities[0].Client.LastName"
                        value="Tester" /> 2
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      Tester, Test
                    </td>
                    <td class="pull-right">
                      <input type="submit" value="Remove" class="btn btn-default input-responsive" formaction="/Application/Edit/2?removeAsa=0" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
          <div id="emi" class="panel panel-default">
            <div id="emi-collapse" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="EmiDeductible">EMI Base Deductible</label>
                  <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input class="form-control input-right-align" id="EmiDeductible" name="EmiDeductible" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-emi-deduct="Must be a multiple of 5, no less than 5, and no greater than 60&#x200E;" data-val-number="The field EMI Base Deductible must be a number."
                      value="40.00" />
                    <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="EmiDeductible" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="EmiReducedDeductibleOption">EMI Reduced Deductible Option&#x200E;</label>
                  <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                      <input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The EMI Reduced Deductible Option&#x200E; field is required." id="EmiReducedDeductibleOption" name="EmiReducedDeductibleOption" type="checkbox" value="true" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="EmiHighDollar">EMI High Dollar</label>‎
                  <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                      ‎<input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The EMI High Dollar field is required." id="EmiHighDollar" name="EmiHighDollar" type="checkbox" value="true" /></div>
                    <div id="emi-base-deductible-high-dollar-value" class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-2"> ‎
                        <select ‎ ‎ class="form-control input-sm" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field DollarId must be a number." id="DollarId" name="DollarId"><option value="100.00">$100</option>
<option selected="selected" value="75.00">$75</option>
</select></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="signature" class="panel panel-default">
            <div data-toggle="collapse" href="#signature-collapse" class="panel-heading collapse-toggle">
              Signature
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up pull-right collapse-arrow"></span>
            </div>
            <div id="signature-collapse" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>
                        Required
                      </th>
                      <th>
                        Name
                      </th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <input id="signature-required-0" type="checkbox" onchange="updateSignatureRequiredValue(0, this.checked)" />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        Tester, Test
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <input id="signature-required-1" type="checkbox" checked="checked" onchange="updateSignatureRequiredValue(1, this.checked)" />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        Test2, Test2
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>

                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <hr />
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `key` is the name of a form element not the id

Answer (score 0):

SEVERAL issues

1. it is window, not windows
2. it is `window.onload=dataLoad;` without the ()
3. if you use the field name then you need to do
   `field = document.querySelector("[name="+key+"]");`
4. You have get more than one radio with the same name, you may want to loop
5. `field.checked = value;` is not what you want but
   `field.checked = field.value==value`
6. You need to include jQuery
7. Since you use jQuery you do not need 1 and 2:

---

```
$(function() {
  dataLoad();
});
```

Comment: Even After making suggested changes, I am not getting values from local storage.

Comment: Surprisingly no errors at all. But value is not getting overwritten.

Comment: Please update your question with html. If you click `<>` you can create a [mcve]

Comment: i have added the html code. Can you please guide now?

Comment: Hi Tina. No, you have added the ASP code. I cannot use ASP. Please post a [mcve] with just enough fields to test the issue. Right click your web page and copy the html into a snippet (click `<>` to create one)

Comment: Can you please check now.

Comment: @Tina Please see update - since localStorage is not allowed at SO, can you look in the console when you run your page from your server?

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I couldnt figure out the solution this way. So I changed my approach. I ended up using http://www.developerdrive.com/2013/08/jquery-plugin-for-caching-forms-using-html5-local-storage/